# How can I copy tables from one SQL Server database to another using Visual Studio 2010 & SQLEXPRESS

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express

I have two *.mdf databases and trying to copy the ASP.NET membership tables from one to the other.

I have tried the data\schema compare tool which I am either not using correctly or it won't find anything to add\update for some reason.

Publish to provider created an sql file with the data and schema. Don't know how  I can use it from within VS to pull some tables I need and add to another existing database.

Is there a console or something I can launch a query from for SQL Server Express to copy tables from one of the db's in its DATA directory to another ?

**Update:** Just used the import/export data wizard. It finally copied all my tables without error but for some reason did not retain the relationship data/foreign keys. The tables that I copied over to the other database did not exist on the database, so no type conflict could arise but it still didn't copy the diagram and relationships.

Comment: If it's a once off thing, use the SSIS components built in to SSMS. Mount both databases, right click on the destination database and choose *Import Data*. Follow the wizard.

Comment: Just used the import/export data wizard. It finally copied all my tables without error but for some reason did not retain the relationship data.

Comment: If you need relationships then you can use Generate Scripts with script constraints and data.

Comment: Is this in the same utility, or is that the publish to provider wizard ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178078.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Is it require to Copy in real time?..i had made code that copy Data from Sqlserver to MySql but it's real time and if you want to copy data not in real time then You Have to Use Migration toolkit.